# How to find fuzzy matched commands in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

In bash when I type

```
icc
```

I get

```
No command 'icc' found, but there are 27 similar ones
```

How do I find these 27 similar commands?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197633/any-way-to-list-similar-commands

Comment: @sat That doesn't look related at all.

Comment: Based on edit distance which is usually used for spelling check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the max limit is 15, you can temporary change this as below;

find CommandNotFound.py

```
sudo find / -name "CommandNotFound.py"
```

open this file with root privilege;

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py
```

change max_len 15 to 150  ;

```
def print_spelling_suggestion(self, word, min_len=3, max_len=150):
```

or change as below;

```
...
 #if len(possible_alternatives) > max_len:
 #    print(_("No command '%s' found, but there are %s similar ones") % (word, len(possible_alternatives)), file=sys.stderr)
 #elif len(possible_alternatives) > 0:
 if len(possible_alternatives) > 0:
            print(_("No command '%s' found, did you mean:") % word, file=sys.stderr)
            for (w, p, c) in possible_alternatives:
                print(_(" Command '%s' from package '%s' (%s)") % (w, p, c), file=sys.stderr)
...
```

test

```
$ icc
No command 'icc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'hcc' from package 'uhexen2' (multiverse)
 Command 'hcc' from package 'lam4-dev' (universe)
 Command 'kcc' from package 'kcc' (universe)
 Command 'fcc' from package 'fcc' (universe)
 Command 'ico' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
 Command 'zcc' from package 'z88dk-bin' (universe)
 Command 'gcc' from package 'gcc' (main)
 Command 'cc' from package 'clang-3.4' (universe)
 Command 'cc' from package 'clang-3.5' (universe)
 Command 'cc' from package 'tcc' (universe)
 Command 'cc' from package 'clang-3.3' (universe)
 Command 'cc' from package 'gcc' (main)
 Command 'ecc' from package 'ecere-dev' (universe)
 Command 'rcc' from package 'qtchooser' (main)
 Command 'iac' from package 'libpolyorb2-dev' (universe)
 Command 'xicc' from package 'xicc' (universe)
 Command 'inc' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'inc' from package 'mailutils-mh' (universe)
 Command 'tcc' from package 'tcc' (universe)
 Command 'ick' from package 'intercal' (universe)
 Command 'ucc' from package 'exult-studio' (multiverse)
 Command 'bcc' from package 'bcc' (main)
 Command 'icp' from package 'renameutils' (universe)
 Command 'ica' from package 'italc-client' (universe)
 Command 'irc' from package 'epic5' (universe)
 Command 'irc' from package 'epic4' (universe)
 Command 'irc' from package 'ircii' (universe)
 Command 'imc' from package 'italc-management-console' (universe)
 Command 'ncc' from package 'tinyos-tools' (universe)
 Command 'scc' from package 'scheme2c' (universe)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you.